# How to get a count on how many words are different 2 strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want a count on how many words have changed in 2 strings. I built a super simple barbaric way.

```
before = "one two three four"
after  = "one six three four five"


word_count_before = before.scan(/\w+/).size
word_count_after  = after.scan(/\w+/).size

if  word_count_before > word_count_after #if the string got smaller we still want a positive number when comparing the two
  bigger  = word_count_before
  smaller = word_count_after
else
  bigger  = word_count_after
  smaller = word_count_before
end

word_difference  =  bigger - smaller
```

Problem with this is it only counts how many words were added or taken away. With my method the end result would be 1 word has changed when 2 words have changed ('two' => 'six' & 'five' was added).

I cant find a way to get how many words in a string have changed. But I have seen examples of places that have something similar (well a more complicated version). Stackoverflow edit suggestions feature has a display that shows a before and after and what words have changed, been replaced, or removed on a post. Also when committing to bitbucket or git you can see what has changed in files between commits. I'm just looking for a count on the number of words that have changed but these examples might help.

Whats a way to do this in ruby or RoR?

Comment: Oops sorry left it there from my coding. Just removed it

Answer (score 2):

```
before = "one two three four".split(" ")        # => ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

after  = "one six three four five".split(" ")   # => ["one", "six", "three", "four", "five"]


after - before  # => ["six", "five"]  These words were added

before - after  # => ["two"]  These words were removed
```

Answer (score 1):

```
before = "one two three four"
after  = "one six three four five"

before, after = [before, after].map(&:split)
common = [before, after].reduce &:&

before_not_after = before - common
after_not_before = after - common
```

To preserve all but one equal strings, one might use:

```
before, after = [before, after].map(&:split)
# after execution of the line below, before array will contain result
after.each { |e| (i = before.index(e)) && before.delete_at(i) }
```

Please be aware that the latter mutates an array `before`.

Comment: Not quite exactly what i'm after. e.g. before = "one one one two" after = "one two" will have as nothing has changed.

Comment: You did not mention in the OP how the equal strings should be treated. Both me and Sergio understood that they should be all removed.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to measure the difference between two texts, there are various algorithms that do just that.
Take a look at eg [levenshtein](https://rubygems.org/gems/levenshtein/versions/0.2.2)

If the words themselves are the same and it is rather about comparing the place of them in the the texts, I can give you this method which I made in a e-book comparing project. This goes a step further than your sample.

"one two three four" and "one four two four" would be the same in your implementation but not with this one.

```
one   = "een redelijk lange tekst om na te gaan of dit programma het verschil kan maken tussen soortgelijke teksten door rekening te houden met combinaties van woorden"
two   = "een redelijk lange tekst met bijna dezelfde woorden als de vorige om na te gaan of dit programma het verschil kan maken tussen soortgelijke teksten door rekening te houden met combinaties van woorden"
three = "een totaal andere tekst, ik maak hem lang genoeg om representabel te zijn en zet er enkele woorden bij die in de eerste tekst ook voorkomen"

class String
    def similarities_with text, lookafter_count=2, lookbefore_count=2
        r = [self.split, text.split].each.inject([]) do |r, a|
            r << a.each_with_index.inject([]) do |m, (element, index)|
              m << a[index-lookbefore_count..index+lookafter_count]
            end
        end
    (r.first & r.last).reject(&:empty?).count
    end
end

one.similarities_with one # 24
one.similarities_with two # 20
one.similarities_with three # 0
"one two three four".similarities_with("one six three four five", 0, 0) # 3
"one two three four".similarities_with("one six three four five", 1, 1) # 0

# and now the difference
one.similarities_with(one) - one.similarities_with(two) # 4
```

Some explanation: The method compares the string itself with the one in the parameter. I use inject so that I don't have to define empty arrays in advance.
The result (r) keeps an array of the word combinations before and after the keywords. These two arrays are compared and only those who are present in both texts are counted and returned by the method.